# Getting rid of incompatible pointer warning

Tags: c

I am getting this warning when compiling my code:

```
varfuncs.c:22:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

How do I compile without warning, or should I use casting?

This is the code:

```
niko: snippets $ cat varfuncs.c 
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_func_t)(char *param1,int param2, ...); 

void func1(char *p1,int p2);
void func2(char *p1,int p2,float p3);
void func3(char *p1,int p2,char *p3);

void func1(char *p1,int p2) {
    printf("p1=%s,p2=%d\n",p1,p2);
}
void func2(char *p1,int p2,float p3) {
    printf("p1=%s,p2=%d,p3=%f\n",p1,p2,p3);
}
void func3(char *p1,int p2,char *p3) {
    printf("p1=%s,p2=%d,p3=%s\n",p1,p2,p3);
}

int main(void) {

    callback_func_t callback_functions[3]={
        func1,
        func2,
        func3
    };

    callback_func_t cb_func;

    cb_func=callback_functions[0];
    cb_func("param1",2);

    cb_func=callback_functions[1];
    cb_func("param1",2,3.333);

    cb_func=callback_functions[2];
    cb_func("param1",2,"param3");


    return 0;
}
niko: snippets $ gcc -g -Wl,--warn-common -ffunction-sections -fshort-enums -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused -Winline -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wformat -o varfuncs varfuncs.c
varfuncs.c: In function ‘main’:
varfuncs.c:22:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   func1,
   ^
varfuncs.c:22:3: note: (near initialization for ‘callback_functions[0]’)
varfuncs.c:23:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   func2,
   ^
varfuncs.c:23:3: note: (near initialization for ‘callback_functions[1]’)
varfuncs.c:24:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   func3
   ^
varfuncs.c:24:3: note: (near initialization for ‘callback_functions[2]’)
niko: snippets $
```

Quick note: the callback_functions[] array will be big, like 200 elements or probably more, so I need function pointers to be stored in an array. As you note, only first two parameters are fixed, and after that it may vary. This is why I wanted to avoid casting, because it will be a huge switch() statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Your function signatures are not compatible, and the compiler is preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot.

You cannot use a variadic function pointer to point to non-variadic functions.  The *call site* must know what types the invoked function expects (for example, it might need to know how to push arguments onto the stack).

If you really want to do this, you should make `func1`, `func2`, etc. all variadic with matching signatures, and each of them should unpack `va_args` in whatever specific way it wants.

Comment: I would also suggest using a pointer to void ( `void*`) for the 3rd and additional parameters ( maybe passed in a `pointer` to a `struct` ) to pass additional argument. I would require to add some typecast to the desired type of the argument. This it how pthread handle passing arguments to thread body functions.

Comment: If I can't do it the compiler should report an "error" , not a "warning". Are you sure about it?

Comment: @dvhh great idea! I think I am going to use (void*) because I will not have very long list of parameters but I do have dozens of typedefs, so, (void*) will work. The only disadvantage, I will have to pass NULL to fill the unused parameters. You may post your comment as an answer, I think it is a very good idea.

Comment: @Nulik The compiler explicitly stated in its warning message that the types are incompatible.  The compiler knows what it's talking about.  I suspect it's a warning and not an error because casting between different types of function pointers is legal *if* you later cast the function pointer back to its original type before invoking it.

Comment: thanks **Nulik**  for the suggestion, but I think that @jamesdlin message is more important for future users who would like an answer for the same error message. Applying the *fix*, would be dangerous if the developer did not understand the root of the issue.

Comment: @Nulik: To have GCC make it an error use the option `-Werror`.